# Alternative to systemd in WSL2 for Kafka installation

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, systemd, systemctl, wsl-2

I am trying to install Kafka in WSL2.

I am referring this DigitalOcean [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-18-04), but I am stuck when trying to start Kafka using the command:

```
sudo systemctl start kafka

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I have researched and found WSL2 does not come with `systemd`. Is there an alternative to install `systemd` services supported in WSL2?

If not, is there a way to install Kafka on Windows?

Comment: There are so many reasons why systemd sucks: https://sysdfree.wordpress.com/2020/01/05/294/, https://lwn.net/Articles/777595/, https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18873851...  Look here forInstalling Kafka on Other WSL: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/app01.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use  the provided `kafka-server-start` script , otherwise you'd need to create a Windows Service, assuming you're trying to get the server to start up along with the booting the machine.